# How can I improve the light?

Tags: lighting, mirror, glass

I am trying to imitate this video, and learn by setting light the same way. Because I don't know how to do it properly, I am trying to cheat and set it where technically it should not be - just to make an illusion. I want to achieve as close as possible effect. How can I do it? I can send the blend file if you have any ideas :)

video:
https://pl.pinterest.com/pin/304344887327105026/

[image]

Comment: These effects are added in the compositor as they are not surface responses

Comment: Thank you for your answear. Take a look on the video - I need help with the lights setup, to make it like that.

Comment: the video link is invalid and doesn't work. It leads to an error page.

Comment: to add to Allen's comment, the effect in the compositor is called Filter > Glare. We can't see any video and I'm not sure we can find the light setup from the video, but maybe use several Area lights?

Comment: https://v.pinimg.com/videos/mc/720p/17/14/00/1714002e89eeb2d68e71286cafeb2526.mp4 
what about this link?